# I want to create a nested function in R

Tags: r, function

For example, I have variables

```
Store.Number <- c("105, 105, 105, 106, 106, 106, 110, 110, 110, 110")
Date <- c("2017-01-04", "2016-07-06", "2016-04-04", "2017-01-31", "2016-10-31", 
          "2016-05-11", "2017-01-26", "2016-10-28", "2016-07-20", "2016-04-27")
Jan012016 <- c("369",NA,NA.......)
a <- as.Date("01/01/2016", "%m/%d/%Y)
```

I want to write a function such that first loop should check for

```
for i=1
Store.Number[i+1,1] = Store.Number [i,1]
If "True"
abs(Date[i,2] - Date[i+1,2])
Else
abs(Date[i,2] - a)
```

example:

```
Store.Number[2,1] = Store.Number [1,1] > TRUE
Jan012016 = abs(Date[2,2] - Date[1,2])

Else
Jan012016 = abs(Date[i,2] - a)
```

Comment: Given there's apparently a relation between your vectors, you should just stick them in a data.frame.

Answer (score 0):

The functions most commonly used in R to split the data into subsets and perform calculations are probably `tapply` and `aggregate`. In this case, `tapply` gives output closest to what you want, so an example is:

```
Store.Number <- c(105, 105, 105, 106, 106, 106, 110, 110, 110, 110)
Date <- as.Date(c("2017-01-04", "2016-07-06", "2016-04-04", "2017-01-31", "2016-10-31", 
          "2016-05-11", "2017-01-26", "2016-10-28", "2016-07-20", "2016-04-27"), "%Y-%m-%d")
a <- as.Date("01/01/2016", "%m/%d/%Y")

store.diffs <- tapply(Date, Store.Number, function(x)abs(diff(c(a,x))))
Jan012016 <- do.call(c,store.diffs)
names(Jan012016) <- NULL
Jan012016
# Time differences in days
# [1] 369 182  93 396  92 173 391  90 100  84
```

Note that I've got rid of the quotes in your definition of `Store.Number`, and converted `Date` from character to Date.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked, I am new to R therefore I thought that this problem could be solved using nested loop